# pins not showing up in mapView. Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I need to display pins ( annotations ) on a map. Then draw polygon lines from pin to pin ( annotation to annotation )

I receive an array of Doubles that I convert to CLLocationCoordiante2D. the first lat and long values are always 0.0 so I remove those from the array because I don't want any issues there.

I map the doubles to the coordinates, and add them to the mapView

I also included a viewFor function with I thought I don't really need?

the map doesn't zoom to any location and NO pins are shown. I know I need to code that in, I will want a general radius around all the pins. Ill work on that after the pins actually show up.

Also, I don't care about names, I just want the pins to show up.

I have tried setting a single coordinate and still no pin.

The mapView delegate is correctly set in viewDidLoad()

I log the locations in debugger and they show up correct.

```
func createAnnotations() {
    latitude.remove(at: 0)
    longitude.remove(at: 0)

   let coordinates = zip(latitude, longitude).map(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init)

    AppLogger.logInfo("\(coordinates)")

   let annotations = zip(coordinates, names)
       .map { (coordinate, name) -> MKPointAnnotation in
           let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

           annotation.coordinate = coordinate
           annotation.title = name

           return annotation
       }

   mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
   mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

    let identifier = "Annotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.89454659591164, longitude: -87.67463844121563), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.89424383424124, longitude: -87.67461071330482))]

The expected result is when the mapView is shown, we see the pins ( annotations ), and polygon lines connecting them from first pin to last. the draw polygon I can work on later.

Comment: I fixed it!  I didn't create a Coordinate2D array! DOHHHHHHHH!!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you don’t need `viewFor` if you register your annotation view for your annotation, e.g.

```
mapView.register(MKPinAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier))
```

But let’s set that aside for a moment. Let’s focus on the annotation not showing up. There are two possibilities:

1. Make sure you’re actually adding coordinates.

   You’re printing `coordinates`. Try printing `annotations`. I.e., let’s make sure that names wasn’t empty and therefore annotations was empty. If you `zip`/`map` an non-empty array with an empty one, the final result will be empty. (It’s shortened to the minimum array length.)
2. Make sure you `viewFor` is getting called at all.

   Assuming you’ve fixed the first issue, try adding breakpoint or log statement in `viewFor` and make sure it’s getting called. E.g. make sure you set the delegate of the map view, etc.